# How to read a user environment variable in C#?

Tags: c#, environment-variables

How can I read a user specific environment variable? I know how to get a system wide one, like

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SOMETHING");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the other overload of the [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6k3c7b0.aspx) that lets you specify the [EnvironmentVariableTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx).

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variable, target);
```

target can be:
`EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process`,
`EnvironmentVariableTarget.User`,
`EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine`.

Answer (score 7):

It's the same method, just set the second parameter to be `User` as:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("varName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

Comment: I am trying to get username but GetEnvironmentVariable returns null: System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("username", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

Comment: @James I think you're looking for `System.Environment.UserName`.

Answer (score 0):

Use second overload of [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6k3c7b0.aspx) which let's you specify [EnvironmentVariableTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("username");
```