# C# code to clear internet temporary files

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

C#.NET code to clear temporary internet files of internet explorer of any user.

Example: for user afvan0771 , there are temp internet files located at

C:\Users\afvan0771\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

i want to clear all of them through c# code when button is clicked

Comment: So, what's the question here actually? (or) you mean ... you need someone to write the code for you?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and give more insight on how do you want to achieve your goal. Also more insight would help a lot. Right now I doubt anyone can help you since the case is not explained at all.

Comment: tried deleting the files using the path mentioned below
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)
but its not deleting any temp files

Comment: you should not do that... User can clear files himself if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example code:

```
            Directory.Delete(@"C:\examples\Directory", true);
```

Deletes the specified directory and, if indicated, any subdirectories and files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to get the path of temp internet files:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)
```

And then iterate over the directory and sub directories to delete filesa and folders

[edit]
I just see that you want user specific environment variable. Maybe this question could help you:
[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403895/how-to-read-a-user-environment-variable-in-c)